# Testing of Inapp Purchase using Prime31 plugin with static response is not supported?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, prime31

I am testing my Unity 3D app for inappbilling(**using Prime 31 Plugin**) with the static response method and with **product Id** as **android.test.purchased**. It is working fine but when the response is successful the Inapp Listener class does not not return any purchase successful event. **Doesn't the Prime 31 plugin supports static response testing?**
Can anyone please tell me that what could be the possible reason for this.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

In Prime31, for the Android InApp Billing plugin the callback is **purchaseSuccededEvent**.
https://prime31.com/docs#androidIAB

And for the iOS Storekit IAP plugin the callback is **purchaseSuccessfulEvent**.
https://prime31.com/docs#iosStoreKit